# which dimension of parameter matrix has variance of 2/(dim_in + dim_out) in Xavier parameter initialize?

Tags: deep-learning, parameters, nlp, pytorch

I do a small experiment in pytorch code, find that both dimension of parameters matrix has variance of 2/(dim_in + dim_out), Why is both dimension, is only dimension of input is ok?

code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
torch.manual_seed(2022)
w = torch.empty(100, 200)
x = nn.init.xavier_normal_(w)
var = torch.var(x, axis = 0)
print (var.shape, torch.mean(var), torch.std(var), '\n')
var = torch.var(x, axis = 1)
print (var.shape, torch.mean(var), torch.std(var))
```

output:

```
torch.Size([200]) tensor(0.0067) tensor(0.0010)
torch.Size([100]) tensor(0.0067) tensor(0.0007)
```

paper: https://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf

pytorch: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.init.html?highlight=xavier#torch.nn.init.xavier_normal_

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: Why is variance of both dimention is 2/(dim_in + dim_out), is ok just dimension of input ?